# HTML Static Table to PHP Filtered Array

Tags: php

Code I Tried -

```
    <?php
    $htmlContent = '<table border="1" cellpadding="5"><tr bgcolor="E0E0E0">
<th>Process Name
<th>Process ID
<th>Protocol
<th>Local Port
<th>Local Port Name
<th>Local Address
<th>Remote Port
<th>Remote Port Name
<th>Remote Address
<th>Remote Host Name
<th>State
<th>Process Path
<th>Product Name
<th>File Description
<th>File Version
<th>Company
<th>Process Created On
<th>User Name
<th>Process Services
<th>Process Attributes
<th>Added On
<th>Module Filename
<th>Remote IP Country
<th>Window Title
<tr><td bgcolor=#FFFFF0 nowrap>Unknown<td bgcolor=#FFFDF0 nowrap>0<td bgcolor=#FFFCF0 nowrap>TCP<td bgcolor=#FFFBF0 nowrap>5357<td bgcolor=#FFF9F0 nowrap>wsd<td bgcolor=#FFF8F0 nowrap>127.0.0.1<td bgcolor=#FFF7F0 nowrap>49159<td bgcolor=#FFF5F0 nowrap>&nbsp;<td bgcolor=#FFF4F0 nowrap>127.0.0.1<td bgcolor=#FFF3F0 nowrap>SYSTEM-PC<td bgcolor=#FFF1F0 nowrap>Time Wait<td bgcolor=#FFF0F0 nowrap>&nbsp;<td bgcolor=#FEF0F0 nowrap>&nbsp;<td bgcolor=#FDF0F1 nowrap>&nbsp;<td bgcolor=#FBF0F3 nowrap>&nbsp;<td bgcolor=#FAF0F4 nowrap>&nbsp;<td bgcolor=#F9F0F5 nowrap>N/A<td bgcolor=#F7F0F7 nowrap>&nbsp;<td bgcolor=#F6F0F8 nowrap>&nbsp;<td bgcolor=#F5F0F9 nowrap>&nbsp;<td bgcolor=#F3F0FB nowrap>10/5/2017 5:36:00 PM<td bgcolor=#F2F0FC nowrap>&nbsp;<td bgcolor=#F1F0FD nowrap>&nbsp;<td bgcolor=#F0F0FF nowrap>&nbsp;
</table>
    ';

    $DOM = new DOMDocument();
        $DOM->loadHTML($htmlContent);

        $Header = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('th');
        $Detail = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('td');

        //#Get header name of the table
        foreach($Detail as $NodeHeader) 
        {
            $aDataTableHeaderHTML[] = trim($NodeHeader->textContent);
        }
        print_r($aDataTableHeaderHTML);
        die();
    ?>
```

[image: TABLE DATA]

Is it possible to filter, or show only some of `<th>` fields.

The above code creates, array and add it in increment order, and note in proper format.

After storing array, is it possible to show filtered data in bootstrap table.

Comment: Yes, you have two arrays, you can add conditions inside the loop, you can or remove any element of the array

Comment: I'm not sure what you need exactly, but you could also use css: `th:nth-child(8),td:nth-child(8) { display: none }`.